# What is UASF, BIP148, Segwit, Segwit2x?

Tags: segregated-witness, bip148-uasf, segwit2x

I keep reading these terms and I don't follow this everyday. Last I heard was that segwit was suppose to solve the block size debate. What are all these new terms like segwit2x and UASF?